# Apple Pay JS inside a WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, applepay, sfsafariviewcontroller

I'm looking into whether it's possible to embed the Apple Pay JS/Web Payments API within a WKWebView. We have a web app which is embedded within a WKWebView and we'd like to implement Apple Pay without a bridge via JavaScript.

I put together a very basic `ViewController.swift` example as below, making use of the [Apple Pay on the Web Demo](https://applepaydemo.apple.com)

```swift
import UIKit
import WebKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = URL(string:"https://applepaydemo.apple.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
}
```

The Apple Pay button is rendered, but the error message for a non-supported device is also displayed (see below), and the button can't be clicked.

[image]

I assumed this meant that there was no support in this context. I tried again using `SFSafariViewController` and the button is displayed and launches Apple Pay on click. In short - it all works perfectly.

```swift
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class ViewController: UIViewController, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string:"https://applepaydemo.apple.com")!)
        self.present(safariVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

What i'm wondering is whether there's an issue with how i've implemented this for the WkWebView, or whether there's a bug. It would appear that either the button appearing, or the button not working are a bug. Clearly at one level it's believing the WkWebView to be compatible, but not at another. It seems likely that this is a bug to report, but i'm pretty new with Swift so it may be an implementation issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**

Refer:-https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/ApplePay_Guide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014764

**Previous Answer**

You need to disable javascript for it to work. (Possibly for security reasons, as payment is involved)

```
override func loadView() {

        let preferences = WKPreferences()
        preferences.javaScriptEnabled = false
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.preferences = preferences
       // let webview = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
       // let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
```

Comment: that does remove the error but clicking the button doesn't launch Apple Pay. I guess this actually uses JS too.

Comment: Can you confirm on whether you have configured the environment on Xcode in order to use Apple Pay ? If not then refer these links:- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/configuring_your_environment and https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/deva43983eb7?sub=dev44ce8ef13

Comment: I was under the impression looking at the screenshot i.e.  "Your browser or device does not support Apple Pay..." was the issue so I suggested to disable Javascript.

Comment: I'd assume it's fine, since when I switch to the SfSafariViewController the Apple Pay prompt appears as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you may only use ApplePay with SFSafariViewController; this means even though the ApplePay button appears, the transaction flow won't let you continue since ApplePay is not supported within WkWebview.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be supported now. Reference: safari release notes (v16+)
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-16-release-notes

Apple Pay New Features: Added support for allowing scripts to be injected into WKWebView that have used Apple Pay (and vice versa).